# Why am I not receiving a console.log that a new socket user has connected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I'm more or less following the socket.io documentation and trying to apply it to my slightly different project but I believe I'm making some mistake. I've used express-generator to create my project's skeleton and therefore I got app.js file, www file and route files.

I've put this code in www file:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
console.log('Socket is running!');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A User Has Connected: ' + socket.id);
});
```

This code in my footer file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this in my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var socket = io();

});
```

Now I understand that when a request is made, the console should log "A User Has Connected: " + the id of the socket but I'm not getting anything other than "Socket is running!". I assume I'm missing something but can't figure it out and the documentation is using the same code.

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8087');
app.set('port', port);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Comment: does your http server is listening on any port ?

Comment: Why are you calling io as a function? Try writing var socket = io;

Comment: Yes, on port 8087. I added the code for that.

Comment: var socket = io(); is taken straight from the documentation of socket.io. I tried var socket = io; but nothing changed.

Comment: It seems that you're following the base documention which is written for simple nodeJs application but it looks like you're using express so you should rather follow this : https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

Comment: This can be probably solved by looking into the browsers console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the same server instance `express-generator` creates, which is the following line in `www` file

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

To use that, change

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

to

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks a lot.